# SCORM SCO testing framework

Tags: scorm

I'm writing some SCORM SCOs to be embedded in clients' learning management systems but I currently don't have anything to test them on. It seems foolish (to the point of being unprofessional) to just foist these files upon the clients and to hope they "just work".

Is there a simple framework I can use to test a SCORM SCO package? I realise I could spend all day setting up a whole learning management system but if there's something more simple, I'd be really appreciative.

Answer (score 6):

You will definitely want to check out the [SCORM Cloud](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud/). They have a trial version you can use.

Answer (score 2):

There's always the [Test Suite](http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM1_2_TestSuite1_2_7ST_ReadMe.htm) provided by the publishers of the SCORM specification.

Comment: Where's the download link? God I just hate ridiculous sites like that, that require me to read through a wall of text to find one link.

Comment: It's not even on the site...
http://www.adlnet.gov/resources/scorm-version-1-2-conformance-test-suite-version-1-2-7/index.html
this is the download link. Windows only. :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with SCORM 1.2, I'd recommend the Reload Scorm Player.
Tt's free, very easy to install and you don't need to be a tech guy to make use of it.

http://www.reload.ac.uk/new/scormplayer.html

Comment: except that it's buggy, crashes constantly on OSX and you always have to import the package again after making any change. Horrible for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the tools from http://www.ostyn.com/resdownloads.htm both for testing SCORM 1.2 and SCORM 2004. Basicly just a HTML page that wraps the SCO in an iframe with a nice console to keep track of the communicaton.

Answer (score 0):

http://scormpool.com has scorm proxy player with trace log option. Supports SCORM 1.2 and 2004 4-th edition plus you can download player and run it on you local computer.

Comment: Would you happen to be the Alex directly associated to Scormpool? If so, you might want to give full disclosure.

Comment: Yes I am supporting this project, how can I disclosure you think? I am sharing knowledge and my identity takes last place on this

Comment: Have a look at [the FAQ on this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion). Basically you must disclose your affiliation in your answers". So merely mention that you're working on it/are the developer of it/have function X in the project/etc. should do the trick. There's no need to disclose other personal details.